# JQuery - Continuous animation on hover with text-shadow

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

So i'm trying to make this button, with the following markup:

css:

```
.button {
    text-shadow: 0px 7px 0px #3b6e62;
    color: #f2b191;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#"><div class="button">Text</div></a>
```

Now as the user is gonna press this button i want to make it look like it's pressed, by animating the text shadow -7px and the top +7px.

A couple of things should happen:

First, i want the button to animate when the user only hovers. it should animate between 4px and 3px text shadow / 4px top and the original markup.

Than, when the button is pressed it should go all the way down with text shadow -7px and the top +7px. (and go back up after since it's a link on the same page).

I hope this still makes sense.

I've tried many JQuery examples here already but i can't seem to get it to work.
At the moment i'm experimenting with this piece of code:

```
var timer;

    $(".button").hover(function() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $(".button").css('top', '4px');
            $(".button").css('text-shadow', '0px 3px 0px #3b6e62');
        }, 600);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $(".button").css('top', '0px');
            $(".button").css('text-shadow', '0px 7px 0px #3b6e62');
        }, 600);
         // Change the interval as you see fit.
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
```

I can't get it to work the way i intent it too. It just keeps animating only one time on hover.

Comment: Both those `setInterval`s happen at (more or less) the same time. `setInterval` doesn't block. But if you're trying to style the button when it's clicked (not just guessing at how long it's going to take), just use CSS and the `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes.

Comment: If you want to make animation, you should use jQuery animate() method. Moreover, setInterval is a repeated event. I don't think it is what you want to do.

Comment: I've tried jQuery animate, but i can't figure out how to animate the text-shadow property with that.

@minitech: the problem with those pseudo classes is that they don't make the animation loop. I want it to keep looping the animation as long as the mouse hovers over the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle, just see if this is what you want, as what you want is not very clear to me

**Edit**:  set the animation to loop on hover (but now it seems to be playing with what you want when the .button is clicked)

**script**

```
var timer;

$(".button").hover(function() {
  timer = setInterval(function(){
     $(".button").css('top', '4px');
     $(".button").css('text-shadow', '0px 3px 0px #3b6e62');

     setTimeout(function(){
        $(".button").css('top', '0px');
        $(".button").css('text-shadow', '0px 7px 0px #3b6e62');
     },400);
  },800);                     
}, function() {
     clearInterval(timer);
});

$(".button").mousedown(function() {
  $('.button').css({top: '7px'});
});

$('.button').mouseup(function() {
  $('.button').css({top: '0px'});
});
```

also I have changed the transition duration from `1.4s` to `.4s`

and in order to apply **top** property you need to give **`position`**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4BTD4/1/)**

**[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4BTD4/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, i want the animation to loop for as long as the user hovers his mouse on the button. like a continuous animation. This fiddle only animates once and than stops.